# How to improve regression model's performance using xgboost?

Tags: xgboost

Is there common notes/skills that using xgboost solving a regression problem?  Examples or materials?Thx.

Comment: I think this is too broad a question for this forum. This is a very case by case basis question and also probably more appropriate for the "Data Science" stack exchange

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried XGBRegressor? See example below:

```
Xgbm_linear = xgb.XGBRegressor(max_depth=3, learning_rate=0.1, n_estimators=500, 
                           silent=True, objective='reg:linear', nthread=-1, gamma=0,
                           min_child_weight=1, max_delta_step=0, subsample=1, 
                           colsample_bytree=1, colsample_bylevel=1, reg_alpha=0, 
                           reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1, base_score=0.5, 
                           seed=0, missing=None).fit(X_train_matrix, Y_train)
```